# Is there a contradiction between these two concepts in Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I'm studying real analysis from Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis, and I feel confused about some definition in Cauchy sequences and feel like there is a contradiction in some idea, or maybe there isn't because I'm a beginner..

Here I quote the concerned part from Rudin's book:

> If $\{p_{n}\}$ is a sequence in $X$ and if $E_{N}$ consists of the points $p_{N}, p_{N+1}, p_{N+2},...,$ it is clear from the two preceding definitions that $\{p_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\ diam\ E_{N}=0$.

and the mentioned preceding definitions are:

> Def. A sequence $\{p_{n}\}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to be a Cauchy sequence if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $d(p_{n}, p_{m})<\epsilon$ if $n\geq N\ and\ m\geq N.$
>
> Def. Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $X$, and let $S$ be the set of all real numbers of the form $d(p,q)$, with $p,q\in E$. The sup of $S$ is called the diameter of $E$.

According to the first quoted sentence, it means -as I understand- that the distance between the points in the sequence is approaching and converging to $0$ as you increase the index of the sequence to $\infty$.

But doesn't this idea contradict with an example of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge such as a sequence in the space of all rational numbers (e.g. $1/n$ which will never converge in $\mathbb{Q}$)?

How the distances between its elements will converge to zero while the sequence never converges ?

**CORRECTION:**

$1/n$ will converge in $\mathbb{Q}$, so the correct example should be $1/n$ in $(0, \infty)$ for example which will not converge.

Comment: If $X$ is not complete, it would be possible for a sequence on Cauchy sequence to not converge in $X.$  Nonetheless, the diameter of $E_N$ would still go to $0$ as $N$ goes to infinty.  Furthermore, every metric space has a completion.  And, every Cauchy sequence converges in a complete metric space.

Comment: @DougM This is exactly what confuses me and don't understand how this will happen ?

Comment: Every Cauchy sequence converges.  It just might not converge to something in the metric space in which it is defined.

Comment: @DougM Good point, but according to the definition of Cauchy sequence, we consider a sequence as Cauchy with regard to a metric space "A sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to be a Cauchy...", so $\{1/n\}$ is a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ and the first quote says that if it is a cauchy sequence (whether converging or not) then the distances will converge to zero (without mentioning anything about the completion!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where is the problem in your specific example (and in fact, there is none):

For instance, for $x_n=\frac{1}{n},$ we have that $\text{diam}(E_N)=\frac{1}{N}$, which clearly goes to $0$. (and, for instance,  $1/n$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}$. Not on $(0,\infty)$ though, but $\text{diam}({E}_N)$ is still $1/N$ and still goes to $0$ as it should. Note that we are seeing this now as a sequence of real numbers. (see below)).

The fact that distances are real numbers and that the diameter is defined in terms of $\sup$ entails nothing about completion(s) of the space(s). You only need to know $\mathbb{R}$, which you must already know to define a metric space. Then the suprema (and infima) are taken when you consider the *distances* (that is, real numbers), not the elements of the space. This can be a little confusing if you work only on examples of $\mathbb{Q}$. For that, remember the maxim:

**We already know the existence and elementary properties of the real numbers when we are talking about metric spaces.**

You don't even need to know that $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Bottom line:** 
When we analyze the sequence $a_n:=\text{diam}(E_N)$, we are looking at a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, no matter what space are the $p_n$ from.

Comment: So the main point here is that we are looking at the set of suprema which will have a limit 0 even if this 0 is not an element of the set itself, no matter what space are the $p_n$ in. Now that answer makes sense for me :)

Comment: I realized now that $1/n$ will converge in $\mathbb{Q}$, this was a mistake just from lacking of focus, I edited the question to mention the correct example

Comment: @MohammadDorgham That's right! You are transfering a sequence on a metric space $X$ to a sequence on $\mathbb{R}$. When $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ this can be a little confusing, since we focus a lot on saying that when we look at $X$ we are looking at the induced metric, but this is a different problem. Just think at the process as a function $X^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: "Transfering" is not the best word: "associating" is best. But I think you got it :).

Comment: Yea, I got the idea, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the distances between points in a Cauchy sequence get arbitrarily small, but, as you noted, the sequence itself need not converge, and the example you gave is an excellent one if you change $\mathbb{Q}$ to $(0,\infty)$ or even $(0,1]$.

A dangerously naive but also very intuitive way of thinking about this is that a Cauchy sequence always *does* 'converge' in a sense, just not necessarily to something in your set. Again, your example shows this if you change $\mathbb{Q}$ to $(0,\infty)$, simply because the set doesn't include $0$. But $1/n$ converges just fine to $0$ in, for example, $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Good point, but according to the definition of Cauchy sequence, we consider a sequence as Cauchy with regard to the metric space, so $\{1/n\}$ is still a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $ (0, \infty)$ and the first quote says that if it is a cauchy sequence (converging or not) then the distances will converge to zero!

Comment: @MohammadDorgham You know more about this than you let on! And I fully agree with your comment. I was just hoping to clarify a bit for you. These concepts haunt me, too.